# SpringBoot MongoTemplate LookupOperation obtener un Objecto en vez de un Arreglo

Tags: spring-boot

Como se puede devolver un **Objeto** a través de `LookupOperation` de `Spring boot`, sabemos que `LookupOperation` devuelve un **Arreglo** pero como digo quiero que devuelva un **Objecto**.

Tengo los siguientes documentos en mi colección **"documento"** de mi BD MongoDB

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e82110ec7447465ef41832a"),
    "doc_codigo" : "01",
    "doc_nombre" : "DNI"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e82110ec7447465ef41832b"),
    "doc_codigo" : "04",
    "doc_nombre" : "CARNET DE EXTRANJERIA"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e82110ec7447465ef41832c"),
    "doc_codigo" : "07",
    "doc_nombre" : "PASAPORTE"
}
```

tengo los siguientes documentos en mi colección **"accesoDocumento"** de mi BD MongoDB

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e86278a1b64a4b9c6499de8"),
    "documento" : {
        "doc_codigo" : "01"
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e86278a1b64a4b9c6499de9"),
    "documento" : {
        "doc_codigo" : "04"
    }
}
```

En Spring boot tengo las siguientes clases que son las mismas y mismos atributos.
**"Clase Documento"**

```
@Document(collection="documento")
public class Documento {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String doc_codigo;
    private String doc_nombre;

    // Getter, Setter y Constructores
}
```

**"Clase AccesoDocumento"**

```
@Document("accesoDocumento")
public class AccesoDocumento {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private Documento documento;

    // Getter, Setter y Constructores
}
```

Ahora estoy usando un **servicio** y con la ayuda `MongoTemplate` utilizo el `LookupOperation` pero este método me devuelve un **Arreglo** y en mi estructura de mi **"Clase"** y de mi **"BD"** no es un **Arreglo** sino más bien es un **"Objeto"**.

```
@Service
public class AccesoDocumento_servicio {
    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public List<AccesoDocumento> listarTodo2(){
        LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup().
            from("documento").
            localField("documento.doc_codigo").
            foreignField("doc_codigo").
            as("documento");
        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(lookupOperation);
        List<AccesoDocumento> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "accesoDocumento", AccesoDocumento.class).getMappedResults();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Esto es el resultado de cargar mi página al momento de llamar a mi **controlador** que hace uso del **servicio**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo resolver este problema, les pido un favor su apoyo.
NOTA: No quiero cambiar la estructura de mi BD ni de mis clases.

Answer (score 0):

Al hacer el *lookup operation* en Mongo, este trata de buscar todas las posibles coincidencias que hagan la union entre `AccesoDocumento` y `Documento`, por ello es que obtienes un listado.

Buscando un poco en internet, me he topado con la [agregacion Unwind Array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), [conocida en Spring como UnwindOperation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/UnwindOperation.html), pero la recomiendan usar asi: `Aggregation.unwind(String)`.

[Basandome en el ejemplo de la documentacion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#unwind-array) y en [esta respuesta de S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16448763/1305745), lo que hace `unwind` es tomar el objeto padre con un arreglo hijo, y multiplica al padre cada uno conteniendo solo un objeto del arreglo hijo. Algo asi:

```
// Original
[
{
    "id": "123"
    "documento": [
        {"codigo": "1",...},
        {"codigo": "2",...},
        {"codigo": "3",...}
    ]
},
...
]

// Luego del unwind
[
{
    "id": "123"
    "documento": {"codigo": "1",...},
},
{
    "id": "123"
    "documento": {"codigo": "2",...},
},
{
    "id": "123"
    "documento": {"codigo": "3",...},
},
...
]
```

Entonces, propondria a que hicieras lo siguiente en tu agregacion:

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(lookupOperation, 
    Aggregation.unwind("$documento"));
```

**Atencion:** si por alguna razon al ejecutar `lookupOperation` el campo `documento` contuviera un arreglo vacio o nulo, el resultado de tu agregacion omitiria el objeto `AccesoDocumento` de los resultados, a menos que uses el parametro `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` asi: `Aggregation.unwind("$documento", true)`.